# Purpose of class name in a class field?

Tags: c#, class, field

I'm new to C# and this code confuses me everytime.

```
public class Classname
{
    Classname field;
}
```

What is the purpose of this Code.

Comment: It is a private field of the same type You need to post some context to get a better answer.

Comment: A class that contains an instance of the class.

Comment: That code in itself, pretty useless - can you give a more elaborate example of where the code is used? Otherwise the answer is no purpose whatsoever...

Comment: It is not class name in a class field, it is using the power of the object-oriented class. If you will add some methods to this class you can use it inside and outside of this class.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you have two different things. First, you are defining a class:

```
public class Classname
```

"public": whatever you're defining, this will be available for use to other elements of your application (access modifiers is a topic on its own, not relevant to the question).

"class": you're defining a class.

"Classname": you want the class to be named Classname.

Then you start to define what is actually inside your class. That is when you'll start to create instances of this class, every instance will have the stuff you wrote here:

```
Classname field;
```

Every instance of the class Classname will have a field of type Classname and the field will be called "field".

You don't provide any access modifiers (no "public" here), so your field will only be accessible by the methods of the class itself. No one outside of the class would be able to do anything to that field.

"Classname": you field should be a reference to an object of the type Classname. This is an interesting part: you are planning your class in such a way that every instance of your class will reference some instance of the same class. It might end up reference itself or reference nothing (null) or reference some other object, it is up to you how you'll use this field, now you just define that every instance of Classname will have such a reference inside.

"field": your field will be named "field". Not a very informative name, but that's what we have. Again, every instance of Classname will have its own "field" field.

The example itself is not really useful, since no one outside of the Classname can access "field", but since Classname have no methods and no properties, the field is not accessible at all. But once you either make your field public or add methods to your class, your class become a blueprint for some kind of chain of objects, where every object of Classname type will have a link to the next object of the same type, which actually might be useful.